# Why I can pass reference of reference to a function accept reference in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Rust, the following code would work:

```
fn test_slice(slices: &[i32]) {
    println!("{:?}", slices);
}

fn main() {
    let slices:&[i32] = &[1,2,3];
    test_slice(slices);
}
```

However, why the code below would also work instead of giving type mismatch error?

```
fn main() {
    let slices:&[i32] = &[1,2,3];
    test_slice(&&&slices);
}
```

Comment: This is known as “auto-deref”.

Answer (score 0):

I find a reference here: https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html#deref-and-method-calls

Looks like Rust would insert as many `*` as needed automatically to get it right.

Comment: _No, it won't insert `\*`. _ Try this out: ```
let s = String::new();
String::into_bytes(&s);
````
**It won't compile!**

Comment: Inserting `.deref()` or `.deref_mut()` is not the same as inserting `*`. The latter doesn't happen.

Comment: @Siiir `*` calls `deref(_mut)`. The difference with `String` is that it isn't copy, so you can't move it out of dereference of `&String`. You can move non-copy types out of dereference of `Box`, so `String::into_bytes(boxed_string)` would expand to `String::into_bytes(*boxed_string)` and that  would compile.